# Looping over yearly named

Tags: r, dataframe

This feels like a very stupid question but is there a simple way to loop over multiple years in names of a dataframe?
My procedure is *very* simple, I just need to add 3 columns together on a yearly basis:

```
df$ges_2005 <- df$bKU3_2005 + df$bKUe3_2005 + df$bKSch_2005
df$ges_2006 <- df$bKU3_2006 + df$bKUe3_2006 + df$bKSch_2006
df$ges_2007 <- df$bKU3_2007 + df$bKUe3_2007 + df$bKSch_2007
df$ges_2008 <- df$bKU3_2008 + df$bKUe3_2008 + df$bKSch_2008
df$ges_2009 <- df$bKU3_2009 + df$bKUe3_2009 + df$bKSch_2009
df$ges_2010 <- df$bKU3_2010 + df$bKUe3_2010 + df$bKSch_2010
```

The latter variables all exist from years 2000-2018 in my dataframe and I was wondering wether I could somehow get way from copy&pasting this code 20 times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution would look like this:

```
my_function <- function(df, start = 2000, end = 2018) {
  for(i in start:end) {
    df[[paste0("ges_", i)]] <- df[[paste0("gesbKU3_", i)]] + df[[paste0("bKUe3_", i)]] + df[[paste0("bKSch_", i)]]
  }
  return(df)
}

# my_function(df) -> supply your data frame
```

Comment: Thanks so much! this worked like a charm :) I knew it had to be something rather straightforward.